# JavaScript Conversion between ArrayBuffer and String Chinese/Japanese Character issue

Tags: javascript, string, character-encoding, arraybuffer

i'm using [Web Crypto API](https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples). i'm getting from the encrypt/decrypt an ArrayBuffer.

to store the ArrayBuffer, i need to stringify it. i found this example for [this](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/06/How-to-convert-ArrayBuffer-to-and-from-String) job:

```
function ab2str(buf) {
  return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(buf));
}
function str2ab(str) {
  var buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length*2); // 2 bytes for each char
  var bufView = new Uint16Array(buf);
  for (var i=0, strLen=str.length; i < strLen; i++) {
    bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return buf;
}
```

but i'm getting not the original string. abstract example workflow:

```
var encryptedArrayBuffer = webcryapto.encrypt("someLongString");
var encryptedString = ab2str(encryptedArrayBuffer);
```

now i get a string with chinese or japanese characters.

```
var decryptedArrayBuffer = webcryapto.decrypt(someKey);
var decryptedString = ab2str(encryptedString);
```

after conversion the depcrypted string isn't like the original. in my array of data some values are decrypted correctly. the others have chinese/japanese characters included like the encrypted value.

is there any good solution to get not unexpected characters?

**UPDATE**

i'm using "AES-CBC" of the web crypto examples above.

*working value*

```
plain = "{"Key":"Outbuildings#58dc9e89-cbf6-4b06-ae9d-3380803ae995","Value":"Sonstiges Nebengebäude"}"

encryptedAB = webcrypto.encrypt(plain)

encrypted = ab2str(encryptedAB)

encrypted => "鷨捍⩆ኅ읲☹많ᦞ㙝⵱芾⟷㾌㴵꾂큹锩凉㚣䬶⁐薈Ⴞ舢ử揼߱泏넸붛蚔缍꠿䌩턂煮铈氁覞⺛鱂髽ؠ읰픡忧㣑鎜ㆅ鍏ᾪ莍庉떹Ẋ昭婚篥．矧ㇴ⒕ࡹ텾᧫ᲈﺍ⮣䋅"

decryptedArrayBuffer = webcrypto.decrypt(encrypted) 

decrypted = ab2str(decryptedArrayBuffer)

decrypted = > "{"Key":"Outbuildings#58dc9e89-cbf6-4b06-ae9d-3380803ae995","Value":"Sonstiges Nebengebäude"}"
```

after decrypting , i get my plain.

*not working value*

```
plainString = "{"Key": "Outbuildings#d24857bc-5dee-4236-835d-8e3b91567a91", "Value": "Werkstatt"}"

encryptedArrayBuffer = webcrypto.encrypt(plainString)

encrypted => ab2str(encryptedArrayBuffer )

encrypted = "鷨捍⩆ኅ읲☹많ᦞ㙝⵱芾⟷㾌㴵꾂큹곙㤴ǌǃ⻲︽㙙郬쵸납餵逳䣊ᯗ퇟姛쏱阵巍旿柀⤏뙡뷇劺泴姲娯趱ៜ쪉轮댼롲ᾕ鱁ᬩ㩋䄅ᖯ苊脭䚛뮖ꡞಅ₨ፂ쑱眈盼갚⊙媌콠ᕥ䲵뺜঳왶輄繆緸䜁ꓳ镉⎇繆催ᥤ՘ⴸ㗻"

decryptedAB = webcrypto.decrypt(encrypted)

decrypted = ab2st(decryptedAB)

decrypted => "{"Key":"Outbuildings#d24∲姅�㉍猨씁�熢ᅍ攄稲짷业鯌㰸35d-иe3ꑢ專䫚︙绬ோᲬ㎂1","V偡lue":"Werkstatt"}"
```

in this example, the GUID and the word "Value" is destroyed, after ab2str(decryptedArrayBuffer). but it's not on all values the same corrupted characters. one part of values are ok, the others destroyed on different characters.

Comment: Can you give a non-working example? It works for me.

Comment: i updated my post. hope the infos are useful

Comment: You are sometimes mixing quotes, the code is not valid but i will assume the outer quotes are supposed to be `'`.

Comment: in original the plain strings are JSON.stringify(jsonObject)

Comment: You are also encrypting the string again: `decryptedAB = webcrypto.encrypt(encrypted)` - i assume that's not your actual code either (because the decrypted would not look anything like the input then), but all this is making me worry your code has some simple issue that isn't reflected in the question.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jzthg7oy/80/ - i can't figure out why your code is not working from the partly invalid and erroneous pseudocode you posted.

Comment: oh sorry, for me it was to late on day.... it was written error. i updated the misstake. there isn't a encryption again... decrypt was meant..

Comment: thank you for help.... now i'm ending uo do rewrite the code of my colleague